# Pandas double(?) groupby with overlaping coordinates

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I need help in solving the following problem.
I can do that in loop, but it's interesting if someone can solve it in pythonic way.

Say we have a dataframe with production parts, each can have many defects. Defects have type, although not all of them are present on every part.
Each defect has a severity (1 to 5, 5 is the worst) and coordinate of beginning and end of the defect.  Defects are independent and can arbitrarily overlap.

**How to produce a dataframe, that contains sections of each part with the worst defect severity on that section?**

For example:

If there are 3 defects 
A with coordinates 10,100, severity 3; 
B with coordinates 40, 50, severity 5 (B is fully in the A);
C with coordinates 80,120, severity 4 (C overlaps with A);
then we should get a dataframe:

```
part_id severity start end
1        3        10   40
1        5        40   50
1        3        50   80
1        4        80   120
```

For a bigger df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['part_id', 'defect_type', 'severity', 'start', 'end'],
             data=[[1,12, 4,1,  10],
                   [1,14, 3,5,  100],
                   [1,10, 1,50, 110],
                   [1,102,3,1,  10],
                   [1,10, 2,200,500],
                   [1,10, 5,300,400],
                   [1,102,1,100,1000],
                   [2,11, 4,2, 10],
                   [2,14, 5,5, 100],
                   [2,102,1,50,110],
                   [2,12, 3,1,10],
                   [2,11, 2,200, 500],
                   [2,14, 4,350, 400],
                   [2,102,1,300, 2000]])
```

result for the part_no=1 would be:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['part_id', 'defect_type', 'severity', 'start', 'end'],
             data=[[1, 4,  1,  10],
                   [1, 3, 10, 100], 
                   [1, 1,100, 110], # can be combined with next row
                   [1, 1,110, 200],
                   [1, 2,200, 300],
                   [1, 5,300, 400],
                   [1, 2,400, 500],
                   [1, 1,500,1000],
                   ])
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to produce a dataframe, that contains sections of each part with the worst defect severity on that section?

Comment: Adding the loop code mentioned make it easier to answer correctly.

Comment: ok, lets do it with a loop

Comment: `groupby` with `max` ?